# gdal2tiles is not recognized as an internal or external command?

Tags: python, gdal, qgis-3, osgeo4w, gdal2tiles

I try to follow this guide ► [Creating super-overlays with gdal2tiles](https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/raster#tile), everything goes well until it reachs gdal2tiles part.

When I type the command `gdal2tiles.py -p geodetic -k bluemarble2.vrt` or `gdal2tiles.py` or `gdal2tiles` in OSGeo4W Shell it gives following result:

> **'gdal2tiles' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

I tried almost everything, searched Google for 2 days, added paths in Windows Environment Variables, installed-uninstalled separate OSGeo4W, experimented with different python versions. And still no any improvement.

Details: At the moment my OSGeoW4 (path: `"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.12\OSGeo4W.bat"`) is the one which comes with [QGIS 3.12](https://qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.12.3-1-Setup-x86_64.exe), and this installation has its own Python 3.7 (path: `"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.12\apps\Python37\python.exe"`) as well.

As google searching showed I am not the only one who has such problem, so does anyone know how to solve this issue?

**► UPDATE [08:20 2020-06-18]**

After @ian-turton's answer I've installed python bindings, but now when I run the command `gdal2tiles.py -p geodetic -k bluemarble2.vrt` it opens actual python file gdal2tiles.py in my VS Code editor.

[image: python bindings]

[image: Shell and VS Code]

Comment: did you install the gdal-python bindings? I don't think they are on by default

Comment: I installed them on separate OSGeoW4 and had no success in solving the issue. Anyway I will do it again in this directory.

Comment: You should only have (and need) one OSGEO4W install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the python bindings for GDAL.

The easiest way is to use the Osgeo4w installer and make sure to check the gdal-python box in the installer.

You need to use the advanced install option and expand the libs item to find gdal-python.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just run `py3_env` first, then everything is fine.