# "The term 'gdal2tiles.py' is not recognized" error and then gdal2tiles.py script opens instead of running after adding necessary system variables

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, osgeo4w, gdal2tiles

I'm using GDAL 3.3.1 installed via OSGeo4w. I ran `gdal2tiles.py world.tif` but it said

```
gdal2tiles.py : The term 'gdal2tiles.py' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ gdal2tiles.py earth.tif
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gdal2tiles.py:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

**Attempts in solving**

- I reinstalled "python3-gdal: The GDAL/OGR Python3 Bindings and Scripts' via the OSGeo4W installer. Same error.
- Add `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts` to the "Path" System Variable. No error but the gdal2tiles.py opens instead of running.The script is in this folder.
- Add  `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils` to the "Path" System Variable. No error but the gdal2tiles.py opens instead of running.The script is also in this folder.
- Copy-Paste the gdal2tiles.py.tmpl, gdal2tiles.py, and gdal2tiles.bat to the `C:\OSGeo4W\bin` folder (which is also a "Path" System Variable). No error but the gdal2tiles.py opens instead of running

**Related post** [gdal2tiles is not recognized as an internal or external command?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365262/gdal2tiles-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

**Any solutions?**

Comment: Osgeo4W tries to make is easy for the users by configuring paths and environmental variables and by installing some helper batch files but you must have messed up the installation but you can have a try with `python path/to/gdal2tiles.py`.

Comment: Just tried ` C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts\gdal2tiles.py earth.tif` and it opened the script again instead of running correctly.

Comment: Read literally. The `python` is important. It kind of says "start python and run this script". Same kind of error here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413629/using-gdal-calc-py-from-the-osgeow4-shell/413634#413634.

Comment: It worked!!! What do you think I should do to correctly use gdal2tiles.py instead of using the `python path/to/gdal2tiles.py` method? I already set the "PYTHONHOME" system variable to `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39`.

Comment: When you have `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts` in the path you can use just `gdal2tiles` or `gdal2tiles.bat`. Both mean the same, the batch file is running `python gdal2tiles.py`for you. Or then you can use the latter directly.

Comment: I figured that's the solution. However, when I did that it says `python: can't open file 'C:\apps\Python39\Scripts\gdal2tiles.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. So I just changed the 3rd line of gdal2tiles.bat from `python "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python39\Scripts\gdal2tiles.py" %*` to `python "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts\gdal2tiles.py" %*` and it says first `The system cannot find the path specified.` then the script runs as intended.

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks in your posts.

Answer (score -1):

A good workaround that doesn't need to type the full path of the Python script nor edit the .bat file is to to add the 'C:\OSGeo4W' to the "Path" system variable.

I can now run gdal2tiles and other scripts located in the `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts` folder just by running its name or its .bat file.

Comment: Don't do this unless you set every other environment variable that the osgeo batch files do.  Just run the "osgeo shell" from the start menu and run things from there